# How to return a promise that resolves customized data from API Javascript

Tags: javascript, api, asynchronous, promise

So I'm using the API of [National Weather Service](https://www.weather.gov/documentation/services-web-api) to create a weather app. But the fetched data is very complicated, and I need to fetch two different APIs. So I want to write a customized async function that returns a promise, which resolves to an object that contains only the necessary data I need.

I came up with something like this:

```
async function fetchWeatherAPI(){
    //data that I need
    let data = {};
    
    try {
       const res1 = await fetch(url1);
       const result1 = await res1.json();
       data = {...data , result1.usefulData};
    } catch(error){}

    try {
       const res2 = await fetch(url2);
       const result2 = await res2.json();
       data = {...data, result2.usefulData};
    } catch(error){}

    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
         resolve(data);
    })

}
```

This code is working for me. But the problem is, what if the APIs reject? How can I handle the error so that I can display the error message in the returned promise? I may want something like this:

```
return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    if(...) reject(errrorMessage); 
    resolve(data);
})
```

Comment: `return new Promise` is entirely superfluous. Just `return data`! And, well, return different data which you decide in your `catch` blocks or with some `if..else`. If you want the function to be erroneous on failure, `throw new Error('Some error message')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `return data`.  You're already inside an `async` function and the return value from that function will be the resolved value of the promise that the `async` function already returns:

```
async function fetchWeatherAPI(){
    //data that I need
    let data = {};
    
    const res1 = await fetch(url1);
    const result1 = await res1.json();
    data = {...data , result1.usefulData};

    const res2 = await fetch(url2);
    const result2 = await res2.json();
    data = {...data, result2.usefulData};
    return data;
}
```

In addition, your `catch` blocks are silently eating errors and attempting to continue as if nothing went wrong.  You probably just want the error to propagate back to the caller so if you just remove your `try/catch` blocks, that's what will happen.

And, the `return new Promise()` you have is entirely superfluous and unnecessary (referred to as an anti-pattern).  You can just remove it and `return data` instead.

---

Note: Since the code you show does not show any dependency between your first and second `fetch()` calls, you could run them in parallel and perhaps finish them faster.

```
async function fetchWeatherAPI(){
    //data that I need
    let data = {};

    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
        fetch(url1).then(r => r.json()),
        fetch(url2).then(r => r.json())
    ]);

    return {...data, result1.usefulData, result2.usefulData};
}
```

Or, I often use a helper function in my code when doing a lot of `fetch()` calls:

```
function fetchJson(...args) {
    return fetch(...args).then(r => r.json());
}

async function fetchWeatherAPI() {
    //data that I need
    let data = {};

    const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([
        fetchJson(url1),
        fetchJson(url2)
    ]);

    return { ...data, result1.usefulData, result2.usefulData };
}
```